# Am I using system call/subprocess call correctly?

Tags: python, subprocess, system, allocation, hpc

This code fails when it runs:

```
import datetime
import subprocess

startdate = datetime.datetime(2010,4,9)
for i in range(1): 
    startdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

enddate = datetime.datetime(2010,4,10)
    for i in range(1): 
        enddate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

subprocess.call("sudo mam-list-usagerecords -s \"" + str(startdate) + "\" -e \"" + str(enddate) + " --format csv --full")
```

The program has these errors when it runs:

```
  File "QuestCommand.py", line 12, in <module>
subprocess.call("sudo mam-list-usagerecords -s \"" + str(startdate) + "\" -e \"" + str(enddate) + " --format csv --full")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

I have ran this code multiple times with other ways, changing quotes and whatnot. I am fairly new to system calls and utilizing an HPC allocation database. I am stuck and if anyone can help me with resolving this issue that would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest to first run the intended command from the command line first, then translate it to python. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, pass a *list* containing your command name and its arguments.

```
subprocess.call(["sudo", "mam-list-usagerecords",
                 "-s", str(startdate),
                 "-e", str(enddate),
                 "--format", "csv",
                 "--full"])
```

This avoids the need to even know how the shell will process a command line.

Answer (score 0):

When I first started using some of the subprocess methods I ran into some of the same issues.

Try running your code like this:

```
import datetime
import subprocess
import shlex

startdate = datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 9) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
enddate = datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 10) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
command = (
    "sudo mam-list-usagerecords -s "
    + str(startdate)
    + "-e"
    + str(enddate)
    + " --format csv --full"
)

print(command)
print(type(command))
print(shlex.split(command))
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

OUTPUT:

> sudo mam-list-usagerecords -s 2010-04-10 00:00:00-e2010-04-11 00:00:00 --format csv --full
>
> class 'str'
>
> ['sudo', 'mam-list-usagerecords', '-s', '2010-04-10', '00:00:00-e2010-04-11', '00:00:00', '--format', 'csv', '--full']

(Command output redacted.)

When the kwarg `shell` is set to `False` which is the default, the command may have to be a collection which is what [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) does.

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

[Popen constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

This issue used to confuse me to no end until I found this in the docs.

Comment: Don't create a string that you are just going to split anyway; define a list. This way, you have to ensure you are correctly quoting things for the final string to split correctly.

Comment: This may work well enough if you know what characters your `startdate` and `enddate` string can ever contain, but it fails very badly when substituting arbitrary strings, which can themselves contain literal quotes. Consequently, it's a generally unsafe practice.

Comment: ...as your own quote says, "it is recommended to pass args as a sequence". Generating that sequence explicitly (as opposed to using `shlex.split`) ensures that the splitting happens exactly where the developer intends it to, and not anywhere else.

Comment: I copied and pasted the string concatenation from the question. Indeed there are more robust ways of creating the command. The point is that `shlex.split` is the way to split the command string when a sequence is required. `command` is a string.

Comment: @DMfll, ...when a sequence is required *and your input is a string*, but that's not the case here -- there is no single string provided by the user as a configuration value; the value is completely generated inside the code, so might as well do it right and generate `command` as a list in the first place.

Comment: Look closely. It is indeed a str. I did have to remove some stray quotations inside of the string which made `shlex.split` throw errors.

Comment: @chepner I am not using the split method on a list. I am using `shlex.split`. From the docs: ❝Note shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex cases❞ I have had cases where making a list manually failed.

Comment: I know, but you still had to know how to create a string that `shlex` would properly split. I'm saying, don't "encode" your list of arguments into a shell command in the first place.

Comment: In this case, you had to know that `str(enddate)` wasn't creating a string value that had to be quoted to be correctly parsed as a single word by `shlex.split`.

Comment: @dmfll, "it is a string" **only because the code in the question derives it that way**. That code can be changed; the OP is asking us *how* best to change it. If the OP was getting a string from a command-line argument or a config file or another external source, *then* it wouldn't be amenable to being changed (without modifying their interfaces), but that's not the case here.

Comment: ...and even then, with the values coming from a config file, it would be the safer practice to run the `shlex.split()` on the literal string parsed from the file and only *after* that's complete run substitutions on the individual values that result, such that contents of a substituted parameter can never be split into multiple words.